# Will auto VBA macro run in excel online automatically when you open/refreshing the session

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, vba

I have a VBA macro enabled excel .xlsm file uploaded in oneDrive. The macros run automatically when you open the excel in desktop. Though we cannot operate on macros in online excel, will the auto macros get executed automatically if you open it online.

All the macros operate on excel cells, Is refreshing excel session thru excel graph API equivalent to open the excel?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You're referencing a VBA Macro language, a REST API and a JavaScript library. These are 3 entirely different things and it isn't very clear what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't this easily answerable by just trying it?  If the macros run, then the answer is "yes, they will run".  If they don't run, the answer is "no, they won't run".  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer from Microsoft:
**"Currently, you can't work with macros in Excel Online."**

> https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Work-with-macros-in-Excel-Online-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343
>
> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_online/macro-enabled-excel-files-in-excel-online/00e982dc-688a-47ee-abe7-4d1f01a4ca04
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/excel-online-service-description.aspx